# Load image into `np.array`, force `0..255` RGB values to `0.00..1.00` float values?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I want to load a .PNG into a 2D structure of 1D structures of RGB values. For example, a `16x16` image would be represented as a `16x16x3` array, where the deepest subarray of length `3` is the RGB values.

I know of `PIL` and `numpy`, and tried something along the lines of:

```py
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

# ...

loaded_image = asarray(Image.open('filename.png'))
```

This does indeed make a `16x16x3` `numpy` array, but its of values between `0..255`. I try to then iterate over them and make them between `0.00..1.00`:

```py
for row in range(len(loaded_image)):
  for col in range(len(loaded_image[0])):
    for channel in range(len(loaded_image[0][0])):
      loaded_image[row][col][channel] /= 256
```

But this tells me the array is read-only.

Is there a better method for this? If it matters, I only really care about greyscale (`R = G = B`), so it could actually be a `16x16x1` structure. Is there a method using Python standard libraries?

Comment: "I try to then iterate over them" Have you used Numpy for other tasks before? The entire point is not to write iteration yourself, but rely on Numpy broadcasting. "But this tells me the array is read-only." Did you try making a copy? Or using an operation that produces a new array?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel no, I'm not terribly familiar with `numpy` and in fact I'd love to find an alternative that didn't require it. I looked around for ways to load an image into an array and `numpy` and `PIL` is what I found.

Comment: Also, what happened when you tried putting things like `pil numpy convert greyscale`, or `pil numpy rescale channels` into a search engine?

Comment: The PIL documentation [has an example](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/tutorial.html#converting-between-modes) of the greyscale conversion which you can do before any Numpy stuff. For the rest, see the linked duplicate for an example (the problem you're facing is even simpler, I think).

Comment: There are other image-loading libraries, but as far as I've seen, they all give you the underlying data as a Numpy array. You should learn how to work with this because it is much more convenient and powerful than using native Python lists for this kind of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method numpy.asarray produces a read-only array. Try using numpy.array and then just divide it by 255, as in:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

loaded_image = np.array(Image.open('filename.png'))
loaded_image = loaded_image / 255.
```